# IE8 date time javascript difference

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, internet-explorer-8, momentjs

In JSON I receive a epoch timestamp which I'm trying to convert correctly

```
var d = new Date(1398693600000);
```

- Chrome, Firefox etc = Mon Apr 28 2014 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
- IE8 = Mon Apr 28 07:00:00 PDT 2014

So straight away it's on a different timezone. Not helpful.

Using MomentJS

```
moment(d).format();
```

- Chrome: 2014-04-28T15:00:00+01:00
- IE8: 2014-04-28T07:00:00-07:00

`moment.utc(d).format();`

- Chrome: 2014-04-28T14:00:00+00:00
- IE8: 2014-04-28T14:00:00+00:00

So using UTC gets consistent time across browsers, but it's an hour out. Bear in mind I'm on GMT so that will effect things down the line.

Is it a problem with MomentJS?

So, what do I need to do to sort IE8?  :) I've no doubt the answer is staring me straight in the face.

Cheers

Comment: Is your timezone always `+01:00`? In that case `moment.utc(d).zone('+01:00').format()` should work.

Comment: No, the timezone won't always be +01:00 as it will change again in October (British Summer Time)

Comment: Are you testing these locally on your machine? (you're not using a service, like browserstack.com to test IE)?

Comment: No I have a Virtual Machine running IE8. I'd hook up a jsfiddle or something, but none of them work in IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two dates are the same, just the string representation is different. For instance, these are all the same exact time:

```
new Date('Mon Apr 28 2014 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)');
new Date('Mon Apr 28 07:00:00 PDT 2014');
new Date('2014-04-28T14:00:00+00:00');
new Date('Mon Apr 28 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)');
```

So any calculations and displays should come out correctly. Now, why you are seeing a different timezone seems strange since, AFAIK, every browser simply uses your system clock.

However, you've commented that you're using a virtual machine to test IE. **It is quite likely that that VM has a different timezone set** and that's why you are seeing a different text representation in IE.

Comment: Sonofabi... You're right. The clock on the VM was showing the correct time. But I looked at the timezone and it was on Pacific time (WTF). Changed that and now it's working fine. Sorry about that everyone.